# USA vs Europe fuel injector differences?

Tags: fuel-system, subaru, fuel-injection, fuel-injectors, legacy

This question is out of curiosity as I didn't find any specs or datasheets after plenty searching.  What would the differences in the fuel injector be for Europe vs USA markets?  I've compared electronic parts catalogs for the same model year (2007 3.0R) Subaru Legacy made for European and USA markets.  The fuel rails, seals and o-rings have the same part numbers but the injectors themselves have different part numbers.  Also fuel PSI specs are the same between models according to the two factory service manuals.

EDIT: details after getting my injectors tested;

EDM & JDM part 16611AA660 (12 ohms), 279 @ 43psi open, 81 @ 43psi 3ms

USDM part 16611AA700 : ?

Denso 297-0010 : Advertised as replacement for 16611AA700 in the US

Comment: You need to search further as the different part numbers anay mean different spray patterns etc to meet emissions requirements in different countries.

Comment: You may find that the difference in part numbers relates more to what manufacturers were available in the various territories than anything physically different.

Comment: That is possible. But wouldn't the car manufacturer assign it is own part number which would remaining the same even if the manufacturers part number differs? I know some organisations do that and there is only one right item for the car, while that item might be sourced from different manufacturers depending on location, supply etc.